# Как вывести переменную в код note.js

Tags: node.js

У меня есть код который выводит сообщение в Discord.
Мне нужно, чтоб сообщение было рандомным.

```
var name, danbot, number;

danbot = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5'
];
```

И вот эти значения нужно вывести вместо слова сообщение.

```
client.on('message', message =>{ 
    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    if (message.content == '!кто ты') { 
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // создание ембед сообщения
    embed.setDescription(`**
    Сообщение 
    **`) // описание ембеда
    .setColor('RANDOM') // рандомный цвет ембеда
    message.channel.send(embed) 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать с помощью коллекции.

```js
// функция которая вычисляет рандомное число учитывая диапазон min..max
function randomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// коллекция
const messages = ['Hello', 'Hola', 'Dzień dobry', 'Ciao', 'Salve'];

// вычисляем рандомное число
const index = randomInt(0, messages.length-1);

// наше сообщение живет по адресу `index`
const message = messages[index];

console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, но я нашел способ проще)

```
const danbot = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3'
];

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

${danbot[getRandomInt(danbot.length)]} //Выводит рандомную переменную
```